# Sql Left joining two tables on one column and outer joining on two other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, outer-join

I have two tables, let say

```
Table1
| pk1        | pk2         | pk3         |field1      |
|:-----------|------------:|:-----------:|:-----------|
| 1          | 1           | 1           |        abc1|
| 1          | 1           | 2           |        abc2|
| 2          | 1           | 2           |        abc3|
| 3          | 2           | 1           |        abc4|
| 4          | 1           | 2           |        abc5|
| 5          | 3           | 1           |        abc6|
| 6          | 1           | 1           |        abc7|

Table2
| pk1        | pk2         | pk3         |field2      |
|:-----------|------------:|:-----------:|:-----------|
| 1          | 1           | 1           |         bc1|
| 1          | 3           | 4           |         bc2|
| 2          | 2           | 1           |         bc3|
| 5          | 1           | 2           |         bc4|
| 7          | 3           | 1           |         bc5|
| 8          | 1           | 1           |         bc6|
```

Left joining two tables on pk1 first, so i get records with pk1= 1,2,5

And then full other joining two tables on pk2 and pk3,
so i get this result:

```
| pk1        | pk2         | pk3         |field1      |field2      |
|:-----------|------------:|:-----------:|:-----------|:-----------|
| 1          | 1           | 1           |        abc1|         bc1|
| 1          | 1           | 2           |        abc2|            |
| 1          | 3           | 4           |            |         bc2|
| 2          | 1           | 2           |        abc3|            |
| 2          | 2           | 1           |            |         bc3|
| 5          | 3           | 1           |        abc6|            |
| 5          | 1           | 2           |            |         bc4|
```

Comment: What is your question? PS Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Left, right & full are the three kinds of outer join.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need  an UNION

```
select t1.pk1, t1.pk2, t1.pk3, t1.field1, t2.field2 
from table1 t1
LEFT join  table2 t2 on t1.pk1 = t2.pk1 
    and t1.pk2 = t2.pk2 
      and t1.pk3 = t2.pk3
UNION 
select t2.pk1, t2.pk2, t2.pk3,null, t2.field2 
from table2 t2 
INNER JOIN table1 ON t1.k1 = t2.pk1
order by t1.pk2, t1.pk3, t1.field1, t2.field2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a `full join`:

```
select pk1, pk2, pk3, t1.field1, t2.field2 
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     using (pk1, pk2, pk3);
```